# Magento Cache broke the site

Tags: magento-enterprise, error, cache, ee-1.14, ee-1.14.2.1

I got an issue with the site. I started getting the errors like:

> **File does not exist: /mage/translate.js**
>   **File does not exist: /mage/cookies.js**
>   **client denied by server configuration: /lib/ccard.js**

So there is no `js` in the path because it should be `/js/mage/translate.js`

Also site started redirecting to `index.php` and url became
http://example.com/index.php/index.php/

Everything became broken.

I cleared the `var/cache` folder manually on the server and site is up again.

*Anyone knows what was the reason of this issue and how to reproduce it?*

Magento ver. **1.14.2.1**

All caches are enabled.

Comment: what is current version of magento? do magento upgraded to new version ever?

Comment: @amit_game current version of magento is 1.14.2.1

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs due to the cache size exceeding the available caching storage. You need to increase the cache storage size.

Comment: where can I set this storage size?